# wordpress move to localhost missing css

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to move a wordpress/buddypress web site to my local pc.

I created a virtual host with the exact same host name, copy the code and DB.

It works but every time I change the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file to see the live original site, chrome miss-behave and get stuck.

So I tried to change the site domain on my local pc - I search&replace the code & db export from the site domain to my local domain (e.g. mydomain.com -> mydomainlocal.com), and I reinstall the DB.

The site is running but it seems to be missing some stuff - specifically design stuff, e.g. css is different, and logo display the site name instead of the logo.

It seems like the new domain name triggers a different configuration of the site, or a different theme.

Can someone please explain how to properly move a wordpress site localy with a local domain name?

I read some posts about this issue and it seems I was doing it right, I actually don't understand why the site looks different if I changed all reference both in the code and DB.

Comment: Exhausted [these](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) options?

Comment: As mentioned below, you need to change the URL in your Wordpress Settings, when switching between live and local, or else any page you visit will be redirected using the value here (including CSS and image references). TIP: Don't use the same hostname for local and live. I generally use whatever the domain will be but with .local instead of a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it answer thanks to Nathan Dawson answer, here are the actual steps I did.

1. I switch back to the original DB (in wp-config.php),
2. setup the local host of the original domain mydomain.com (NOTE that I didn't delete the settings of the new local host - mydomainlocal.com)
3. In mydomain.com/wp-admin/options-general.php I changed the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to the new domain mydomainlocal.com
4. click save

After saving this settings the site redirects to the new domain immediately, but since I kept the setting of the new domain it worked, and the problem is solved.

EDIT - a quick and simple solution is simply change "siteurl" and "home" in the database table "wp_options" (through phpMyAdmin or similar)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the problem lies with the fact you've performed a search and replace on the database.

WordPress serializes some data and by running a search and replace on it you'll have changed the lengths therefore breaking the serialization. Often things like theme options are stored in that way and will appear to reset when broken.

In order to update the URL you'll need a more advanced tool like: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Further information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs

Comment: Thank you for the info and links. InterconnectIT script did the job , and the CSS issues are solved.

Answer (score 0):

- First You must change domain name in database **wp-options** table
  where **option_name** is **suteurl** and **home**
- If not help, see in wordpress **admin panel theme settings**, some
  themes have setting and in setting those can have url setting
- In **browser** , in **source** you can find **errors**, and in errors you can see
  not correct urls

Comment: Not in the THeme settings, but in the general Wordpress Settings, the `Site URL` and ¬Wordpress URL` are the options you refer to here. These need to be changed when switching between live and local, or else your site will be looking for CSS/images with the wrong paths.